# Openshift 4 - Mkdir command gets permission denied error

Tags: docker, openshift

I have setup a deployment for an image that doesn't specify any user to run on. When the image starts, it tries to create a directory at `/data/cache` and it encounter permission denied error.

I try to create the directory from the terminal in pods, and encounter the same issue:

```
$ whoami
1000910000
$ mkdir /data/cache
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/data/cache’: Permission denied
```

Found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42363105/permission-denied-mkdir-in-container-on-openshift) but it requires the image to be run as a specific user, and i can't change the Dockerfile. Any way to allow the image write access to `/data`?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you cannot change the container itself, then mounting an `emptyDir` directory in this place could be an option.

Add it like so to the Deployment:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: example-deployment
  labels:
    app: example
spec:
...
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: example
        image: nginx:1.14.2
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /data/cache
          name: cache-volume
      volumes:
      - name: cache-volume
        emptyDir: {}
```

Comment: this should work. another option would be to run the pods created by the container with a specific serviceaccount and add the anyuid scc to this SA

Answer (score 1):

This is due to how OpenShift create/manage the images as every time you deploy, it creates a random user ID.

You should check how to support arbitrary user ids:

https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.7/openshift_images/create-images.html

> Support arbitrary user ids
>
> By default, OpenShift Container Platform runs containers using an
> arbitrarily assigned user ID. This provides additional security
> against processes escaping the container due to a container engine
> vulnerability and thereby achieving escalated permissions on the host
> node.
>
> For an image to support running as an arbitrary user, directories and
> files that are written to by processes in the image must be owned by
> the root group and be read/writable by that group. Files to be
> executed must also have group execute permissions.
>
> Adding the following to your Dockerfile sets the directory and file
> permissions to allow users in the root group to access them in the
> built image:

```
RUN chgrp -R 0 /some/directory && \
    chmod -R g=u /some/directory
```

> Because the container user is always a member of the root group, the
> container user can read and write these files.

So you should really try to bend it following these rules.